# Angular 4 website description at google search

Tags: html, angular, seo

I have created an website in Angular 4/5 (**not** Universal). When i want to find my website in google search then my website has not any description, just title.
Is there any way to change this without using Angular Universal? I dont want any seo optimalization, just this desription.

Comment: Your app use angular routing ?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is an SEO question outside [the scope defined by the SEO tag wiki page](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/seo/info). It might be on-topic for [the webmasters stackexchange](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: Do not close this question. Angular has the API to add meta description tags as provided in my answer.

Comment: Yes my app use routing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add a "description" meta tag in `index.html` . Like the one below.

```
<meta name="description" content="[Your description goes here]">
```

Add your website URL to Google using link below.
https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/submit-url

AND This might take little time to get reflected in Google search.

Google document link - https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/35624?hl=en

Answer (score 2):

Take advantage of the [Meta](https://angular.io/api/platform-browser/Meta) injectable service.

Example usage

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';
import {Meta} from '@angular/platform-browser';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-component',
  template: 'my awesome app'
})
export class AppComponent {
  constructor(private meta: Meta) {
    this.meta.addTag({ 
      name: 'description', 
      content: `My site's description that will show in google`
     })
  }
}
```

Comment: Google crawlers don't see these tags.  My App IS NOT server side renderer - this is problem?